# iPhone - SQLite Insert Statement doesn't work in Release Configuration while works in Debug Config

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite, config, xcode4.6

I am developing a game project like quiz which uses sqlite db for storing data. Everything works fine i.e. reading from and writing to the database in "Debug" configuration and game works as expected.

However, when I build same game in release configuration. The sqlite "insert" and "update" statements are not working as it should. The program crashes after few play due to sqlite db read / write.

I searched for answers in the internet and found few suggestions which says it is optimization problem in release configuration.

Here is my code for inserting new player in sqlite db.

```
- (void) insertPlayerWithName:(NSString *) playerName {

@try
{
    [self openDatabase];

    Player *p = [[Player alloc] init];
    p.name = playerName;
    p.energyRefillDate = [self getStringDateFromNSDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:100000]];

    NSLog(@"Date  : %@", p.energyRefillDate);
    NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO Player VALUES ('%@', %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, '%@', %d)", p.name, p.knop, p.gold, p.energy, p.karma, p.level, p.keyOfEnergy, p.keyOfWisdom, p.keyOfStrength, p.premium, p.energyRefillDate, p.numQuestsCompleted];

    char *error;
    if ( sqlite3_exec(_sqliteDBConnection, [insertSQL UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &error) != SQLITE_OK )
    {
        NSLog(@"Error While Inserting Player : %@", [NSString stringWithUTF8String:error] );
    }
    else
    {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:playerName forKey:@"CurrentPlayer"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        sqlite3_close(_sqliteDBConnection);
    }
    [p release];
}
@catch (NSException *exception)
{
    NSLog(@"An exception while Error While Inserting Player in Sqlite :%@", exception);
}
@finally
{
    sqlite3_close(_sqliteDBConnection);
}
}
```

Any sort of help, suggestions, tips are highly appreciated. Thanks in advance for taking time to read the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. The issue was with the C Preprocessor Flag NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS=1 in release configuration.

When I removed this assertion, the app worked as expected. I hope it would help someone out there who may face this problem.